# Copy a file from client to server via rest end point using golang

Tags: rest, go

I want to copy a file from the client to the server through the rest end point exposed by the server. I referred the various questions and answers in stackoverflow but I could not get a clear picture of it.

I just want a sample client and server code in golang to copy the file from client and save it on the server.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Direction: Server to Client**

So -- both sides are in Go? Okay, let's start with the server side. See my `WebLoad.go` file from my `CSVStorageServer` server: ([Link to Github](https://github.com/SommerEngineering/CSVStorageServer/blob/master/WebLoad.go))

At line 17, I define the handler for the web server. This method will build a zip file on-demand and send it to the browser. The important part regarding to your question are line 77 up to 82. Here, I set the headers for the client, e.g. content length and type. Line 82 sends the whole data to the client side. It copies the bytes from the on-demand zip file to the wire.

On the client side, you trigger e.g. a `GET` request and store the result. Here an example: https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#example_Get

With `http.Get(...` you trigger the `GET` request. With `ioutil.ReadAll(res.Body)` you read all bytes from the server and store it to a variable. Afterwards, you could write the bytes to the disk or process it in-memory.

I hope, this answer helps you.

Best regards, Thorsten

Edit #1:
Regarding the REST end-point, cf. the server definition ([link to Github](https://github.com/SommerEngineering/CSVStorageServer/blob/master/WebServer.go)). Line 16 defines the REST end-point for this handler. In this case, it gets available as `/load`. You could use any REST-like path here, e.g. `/open/file/USERID/send`, etc.

**Direction: Client to Server**

In order to copy a file from client to server side, similar operations are necessary. On the client side, a `POST` request is necessary as `multipart/form-data`. Here is a good example for this: [Link to a blog post](https://astaxie.gitbooks.io/build-web-application-with-golang/en/04.5.html). This example considers also the server part. The relevant client part is the function `func postFile(filename string, targetUrl string) error { ... }`.

For the server part, here an own example: [Link to Github](https://github.com/SommerEngineering/Ocean/blob/50f4836e44a45755ac1095023887bc2fef0e35fb/Admin/HandlerFileUpload.go). This example receives an file from the client and writes it to a MongoDB database. The relevant parts are:

Line 39 read the file from the client: `file, fileHeader, fileError := request.FormFile("file")` The result is a handle to this uploaded file.

Line 60 copies all bytes from the source (browser or Go client) into a destination (here, the MongoDB): `_, errCopy := io.Copy(newFile, file)`.

**Edit #2:**

Here is a full working example: https://github.com/SommerEngineering/Example010 where client and server are in the same program. It should be easy to split it into two programs.

Comment: Thank you so much for answering. I think whatever you have mentioned is for copying the file from the server to the client. Please correct me if I'm wrong. 

But I want it the other way around. I should copy the file from the client and send it to the server !

Comment: Sorry, you are right. I edit my answer in order to consider the other direction as well.

Comment: Thanks again @SommerEngineering. I tried my best to implement it using the links you provided. [Here](https://play.golang.org/p/MpcGX8p61_) is the client code and [here](https://play.golang.org/p/qrrK1e1HVa) is the server code. I'm seeing "Form file error" on the server side. Can you please help me with this ?

Comment: Thanks a ton ! It works like a charm. :) In the case of larger files, is there any way I can send the data in smaller chunks ?

Comment: One more question. in your working example, doesn't the server send a response back to the client ? And why is the client waiting forever ?

Comment: Yes, in case of larger files you should not read it into memory and send it. Instead, open the file for reading and use `io.Copy` (https://golang.org/pkg/io/#Copy) to copy the data to the wire.

Comment: The web server sends at least a status code e.g. `200 OK`, etc. But yes: My code does not send any explicit answer. The client waits forever just to keep the entire program running. The issue is: The web server runs at its own thread i.e. go routine. Without waiting, it could happen that the client is done with sending but the server does not finished reading and / or writing to disk. Thus, waiting guarantees that both parts are fine. Finally, a real-world server would run endless. Thus, this issue never happens there. If the client would be a own program, it could terminated after sending.

Comment: Do you mean to say that io.Copy will itself handle the process of dividing the file into smaller chunks ?

Comment: Yes, io.Copy will copy the file with an internal buffer. Thus, the whole file gets read as chunks.

Comment: Is it possible to send each chunk in a separate request and then build the actual file on the server ?

Comment: I tried to send a file in smaller chunks using io.CopyN(). I'm able to split it into chunks of defined size but I don't know how to complete it. I have written the [client](https://play.golang.org/p/eTsyYuMLAi) which will just send one small chunk of the file and the [server](https://play.golang.org/p/kYagUdeglj) which will store that small chunk. Can you please help me complete it ?